# Defining refresh interval of map in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-rest-api, refresh, kibana

Is it possible to define the map refresh interval on the server-side (GeoServer 2.11)? The issue is the following. I send GetMap requests to GeoServer from Kibana (client-side). Once the response is received, the polygons are colored according to data field's values using SLD rules. However when I set refresh interval in Kibana, it does not apply to the map. So, I want to do this directly from GeoServer.

Is it possible to define 1 minute interval for updating the map and colors of polygons (sending POST request)?

Now each update takes place only when I reload the brower's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible server side. GeoServer doesn't know which client has requested a map from one request to another. You will need to handle this sort of refresh in the client.